# Can I create a wifi hotspot using a computer that connected a wifi already?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

1. Suppose I have my latop-1 that have access to the internet through wifi-A.
2. I want laptop-2 to connect to the internet, however it can't direct connect to wifi-A because the computer is using a terminal environment, it can't access to the browser based login system of wifi-A.
3. Can I creat a wifi hostspot wifi-B using the laptop-1, to share the internet with my laptop-2? Note that the laptop-1 has internet access because it already connected to wifi-A, not wired.

In short, can I create a wifi hot spot using a laptop which already connected to the another wifi?

Comment: Can you connect A & B with a wire ? What's the kind of Wifi ? Is it secured ?

Comment: I don't have a wire. The original wifi is the kind that everyone can connect by it jumps to a webpage require login information @Fana

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but with the proper hardware. Several BCM Wi-Fi cards don't support this, but several others do. You will have to go in network and sharing center and allow sharing your internet connection. Then use a program like MyPublicWifi or maybe follow this guide:

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-set-up-a-wireless-hotspot-From-WiFi-Windows/

The point here is: it is possible; with the proper hardware. If your hardware doesn't support it, no method will work. There is a command to check this (but I can't find it, try Google)